# C++ Passing this to a non Const Function

Tags: c++, pointers, this

Example Class:

```
int i;

 void Classname::a1(const Classname& var){

    var.a2(*this);

 }

 void Classname::a2(const Classname& var){

    var.i = 100;

 }
```

How can i make that work without adding const to a2?

Comment: Why use a `const` reference if you want to change it?

Answer (score 3):

- Short answer - you shouldn't.

  `var` is `const`, meaning you shouldn't be changing anything on it at all; `var.i=100` is going to have very unexpected consequences for other people.
- Longer answer - remove the `const`, or make `i` mutable.

  The `mutable` keyword means that the variable can be changed even if the object is `const`.  Alternatively, by making it non-`const`, you can change it, and people can expect their object to be modified.
- Really nasty answer - cast the `const`-ness away.

  I'm not even going to flesh out this part, because it's so horrid, doing it will result in [a velocoraptor attacking you where you sit](https://xkcd.com/292/).

Comment: Down side of that is that it also increases memory usage, but yes, would also work

Comment: Yes, I am completely agree.